# Form Validation Before Storing to SQLite DB in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, validation

I have a save button. When a user clicks it. The data-input in the the form will be validated before it will be send to the db. How can I achieve it?
Here's the code of my save button.

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int civil_caseI = int.Parse(civil_case.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception cc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Number Only on CIVIL CASE");
    }
    string areaI = area.Text;
    if (areaI.Length <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Area Field must not be Empty");
    }
    string addressI = address.Text;
    if (addressI.Length <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Address Field must not be Empty");
    }
    // HERE WILL BE THE QUERY TO INSERT THE DATA AFTER THE FORM IS VALIDATED.
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking how to do? It looks like you're already doing form validation and just not returning.

Comment: You are already performing some validation, can you specify what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @TomasPastircak i mean..even i perform validation, does it still send the invalid ones or it will only send as long as there is no more invalid types or key-ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning from your method if there is an error in validation. **`return` early from your method** if there is an exception/failure in rule validation. You can just add `return;` statement after showing the error message.

A better way would be to use `int.TryParse` to parse `int` values instead of `try-catch`. Remember exceptions are expensive. You can also use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `addressI.Length <= 0` which will consider white space as invalid values *(if you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher, otherwise use `string.IsNullOrEmpty)*.

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int civil_caseI;
    if (!int.TryParse(civil_case.Text, out civil_caseI))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Number Only on CIVIL CASE");
        return; //add that - early return
    }
    string areaI = area.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaI.Trim()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Area Field must not be Empty");
        return;
    }
    string addressI = address.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(addressI.Trim())) //or addressI.Trim().Length <= 0
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Address Field must not be Empty");
        return;
    }
    //HERE WILL BE THE QUERY TO INSERT THE DATA AFTER THE FORM IS VALIDATED.
}
```

You can also extract out the logic of your validation in a separate method returning `bool` and then call that method for validation.

Comment: but, i got an error. string does not contain definition for IsNullorWhiteSpace @Habib

Comment: @user3569641, it should be `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, make sure the case is same, In your comment it appears that `Or` is `or`. Also it is only supported in applications targeting .Net framework 4.0 or higher. If your application is using .Net framework 3.5 or lower then use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: i am now using IsNullOrEmpty because i'm using 3.5 .Net Framework

Comment: @user3569641, I have modified the code for .Net framework 3.5.